# making an array with a specific size that includes elements in data structure datatype

Tags: c, structure

I want to make an array with 100 elements that include structure data type in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct student{
    char name[20];
    float grade[15];
    struct date{
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    };
};
int main(){
    struct std[100];
    
}
```

Comment: Apart from having `struct` where it should be `struct student` and that you need a member name for the `struct date`, I do not see what you are asking about. Or is is that simple? Consider showing how you intend to access the structure you have in mind.

Comment: I have created an answer in case it IS that simple, or to provoke and facilitate clarification. If you clarify or confirm I will retract my close-vote or vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

With a structure type like this:

```
struct student{
    char name[20];
    float grade[15];
    struct date_tag{
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    } date;
};
```

You can do things like this

```
int main(){
    struct student std[100];

    std[99].grade[14]=1.5;
    std[99].grade[14].date.day=28;
    
}
```

The identifier `date_tag` in that code is called a struct tag.
The corresponding type is `struct date_tag` and it is used to define a member of of that type within the the type `struct student`. The member is called `date`.
Within `main()` an array of `struct student`s is defined and then accessed for demonstration purposes.

Comment: thank you so much. please say me how I can reach the day or month or year in this code.

Comment: I already demonstrated how to access the day, in the last line (apart from }) . Let me know if that is enough or what else you need demonstrated in reaching the desired info.

Comment: thank you again .but so that you say I have a bug like this ``` struct student std[100];
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
  printf("enter student name:\n");
  scanf("%s",&std[i].name);
  printf("enter the day,month and year of student birth date:(in order) ");
  scanf("%d",&std[i].date.day);
  scanf("%d",&std[i].date.month);
  scanf("%d",&std[i].date.year);
  for(int j=0;j<15;j++){
   printf("enter the %d grade of %s:\n",i,std[i].name);
   scanf("%f",&std[i].grade);
  }``` i have this error :17 22 C:\Users\AVAJANG\Documents\Untitled3.cpp [Error] invalid use of 'struct student::date'

Comment: As you can see, showing code in a comment does not work. Also I suspect that you attempt to squeeze a whole new question into comments. Please consider carefully whether you are adding details to this question or asking a new one, which occurred after you got this one answered. If it is new please use the "Ask Question" button again. Otherwise changing this question too much (and away from an existing answer) is considered a "moving target" and not appreciated.